# Angular creating divs with ngFor on an array of objects: How to refresh add another div when another object is added to the Array

Tags: angular

So I have a ngFor  div which generates tabs in a mat tab group

```
   <div *ngFor="let step of validationSteps; let i = index ">
<mat-tab>
</mat-tab>
</div>
```

which gets it data from an Array called validationSteps in my typescript.
If I add a validationStep to the array, how can I get that ngFor to re-run with the changed array of validationSteps?

Comment: Try changing (overwriting) the reference of the Array instead of just pushing a new object in it. If your changedetection is set to onPush, it will not be detected.

Comment: Thanks. I wasnt aware it was that simple, it worked

Comment: Allright, I'll post an answer with documentation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try **changing (overwriting) the reference** of the Array instead of just pushing a new object in it. If your **changedetection** is set to **onPush**, it will not be detected.

You can use [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) or the [Spread Operator](https://www.zeptobook.com/spread-operator-in-typescript/), or simply reassign your array manually.

Details:
https://blog.angular-university.io/onpush-change-detection-how-it-works/